# How can I access, to the row content in a TableView, by clicking the row

Tags: android, lua, widget, tableview, coronasdk

everyone:
This is my problem, I'm trying to show the content of a selected row in a TableView, when I clicked.

In the onRowRender I add the rows by this way,

```
local function onRowRender( event )    
  local row = event.row 
  local myText = ""    
  local myText = display.newText(row,"Text to show",150,row.contentHeight/2,native.systemFontBold,30 )
end
```

In the onRowTouch event I have tried this,

```
local function onRowTouchTable( event )    
  print(menuPedidos._view._rows[row.index]) //it return a table, I assumed the row selected
  print(menuPedidos._view._rows[row.index].mytext) //it return nil
end
```

And what I need, is the text saved in the object **mytext**

I will appreciate any help, thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you should store your data in separate variable, pass it in params in `insertRow` and set row's id also in `insertRow` to reference to them later.

Example

```
for i = 1, #myData do
   myList:insertRow{
      rowHeight = 60,
      id = i,
      isCategory = false,
      rowColor = { 1, 1, 1 },
      lineColor = { 0.90, 0.90, 0.90 },
      params = {
         name = myData[i].name,
         phone = myData[i].phone
      }
   }
end
```

So in `onRowTouchTable` you can do something like that

```
local function onRowTouchTable(event) 
   local row = event.target
   local id = row.index -- or row.id I'm not sure

   print(myData[id])
end
```

More information you find on [Corona blog](https://coronalabs.com/blog/2014/03/04/tutorial-advanced-tableview-tactics/). Also, you can see youtube video [Corona University - Displaying Database Data Using TableView Widgets](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=PXo4Rv5KPjo).

Comment: I don't know another solution.